# How to type the right arrow (i.e., ⇒, not =>) in IntelliJ Mac OS?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

A common symbol to use in Scala pattern matching is the right arrow, either ⇒ or =>. So my question is what is the shortcut to type the neat looking right arrow ⇒? I use IntelliJ on Mac OS.

below is an example code that uses ⇒ from https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/guide/tutorial_1.html

```
package com.lightbend.akka.sample

import akka.actor.{ Actor, Props, ActorSystem }
import scala.io.StdIn

class PrintMyActorRefActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "printit" ⇒
      val secondRef = context.actorOf(Props.empty, "second-actor")
      println(s"Second: $secondRef")
  }
}

object ActorHierarchyExperiments extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("testSystem")

  val firstRef = system.actorOf(Props[PrintMyActorRefActor], "first-actor")
  println(s"First: $firstRef")
  firstRef ! "printit"

  println(">>> Press ENTER to exit <<<")
  try StdIn.readLine()
  finally system.terminate()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most projects that use this symbol, use a tool like [Scalariform](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalariform) to automatically change `=>` into `⇒` after you've written it.

Personally though, I prefer to use a font with ligatures (such as [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode)) to render nice arrows and such.

Answer (score 2):

In your Settings tab (File => Settings in Linux, probably the same/similar on Mac OS), add it as a Live Template through Editor => Live Templates.

[See here for more info](https://themodernlife.github.io/scala/intellij/2014/01/08/scala-unicode-arrows-in-intellij-idea/)