# How to type unicode 'rightwards double arrow' on a keyboard

Tags: scala, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've seen the [unicode rightwards double arrow](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21d2/index.htm) '⇒' as a replacement for '=>' in many scala source files.
Ever since I started programming scala I've wondered whether there is a key sequence for these arrows?
The regular rightwards arrow '→' for instance can be typed with <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question, but _IMHO_ is better to use the **ascii** form `=>`. Some Editors may have troubles with unicode characters. See [this](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-1.0.0.html#org_scalastyle_scalariform_NonASCIICharacterChecker) as a reference.

Comment: Usually, they do not actually replace the characters. Instead, the editor or website in question is using [*font ligatures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature).

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771931/how-to-type-the-right-arrow-i-e-%E2%87%92-not-in-intellij-mac-os/47772215

Answer (score 0):

if you use intellij, go to Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Other

you can toggle "Replace => with unicode symbol" and other options with unicode.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the editor you are using. By the way, you can always replace `=>` with unicode `⇒` in any editor, as some editors are not friendly to **Non-ASCII** characters. But I believe that in Scala replacing `=>` with `⇒` is a bad idea and not recommended as per **Scalastyle**.